# Ignore None values and skip to next value?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, finance, computational-finance

This list of dictionaries changes regularly.

```
search_option = [{'strike_price': '1', 'bid_price': '0.25', 'implied_volatility': '0.94' }, 
{'strike_price': '3.5', 'bid_price': '0.20', 'implied_volatility': '0.88'},
{'strike_price': '2', 'bid_price': '0.05', 'implied_volatility': None}, 
{'strike_price': '3.5', 'bid_price': '0.31', 'implied_volatility': '0.25'}]
```

Here the code searches for an option with an implied volatility below 0.9.

```
for option_list in search_option:
    if option_list is not None:
        option_list = ([i for i in search_option if float(i["implied_volatility"]) < 0.90])
    print(option_list)
```

I occasionally get this error:

*float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'*

**My question is, how can I leave the search the same (implied_volatility < 0.9) while at the same time ignoring the None values?**
In other words, if it's 'None' then skip to the next available option.

Comment: Did that error message start with "ValueError:"?

Comment: Okay, I had to experiment for myself. The error is `TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'`. Don't trim error messages, they contain valuable information.

Comment: Duly noted, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
option_list = ([i for i in search_option if i["implied_volatility"] and float(i["implied_volatility"]) < 0.90])
```

You also do not have to iterate through the `search_option` with a for loop you can just use the code above to replace it.

Comment: Since `None` is considered falsy, it would be enough just testing `if i["implied_volatility"] and float(i["implied_volatility"]) < 0.90`

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in search_option:
if i['implied_volatility'] is not None and float(i['implied_volatility']) < 0.9 :
     print(i)
```

Is this what you want?

Answer (score 1):

Add `if i["implied_volatility"] is not None` before your conditional. Yur entire list comprehension thus becomes:

```
[i for i in search_option if i["implied_volatility"] is not None if float(i["implied_volatility"]) < 0.90]
```

This is the list comprehension equivalent to a nested conditional.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```py
option_list = [so for so in search_option if float(so['implied_volatility'] or '0.95') < 0.90]
print(option_list)
```

Output

```
[{'strike_price': '3.5', 'bid_price': '0.20', 'implied_volatility': '0.88'}, {'strike_price': '3.5', 'bid_price': '0.31', 'implied_volatility': '0.25'}]
```